# Xamarin Android MvvmCross - MvxObservableCollection list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am very new to Mvvmcross and Xamarin Android development. My question are there any examples with the use of MvxObserableCollection method(I read somewhere that this method can help update the list with each api call), I am searching for few hours now but I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

And like I mentioned, in my sample application when user clicks a button an api request is send and the information comes up in second viewmodel but there is a list which is constantly changing with each api call. So is the any other way or are there any MvxObservableCollection examples out there. Thanks!!

Comment: You could read this document : http://www.marcbruins.nl/xamarin-android-reyclerview-with-mvvmcross/

Comment: @YorkShen Thanks!! The example helped a lot.

Comment: Happy coding! : )

Comment: That URL's dead, but [this one](https://www.marcbruins.nl/xamarin-android-reyclerview-binding-with-mvvmcross) works.